# Sentry doesn't show the same information I see in the macOS Console app

Tags: xcode, macos, sentry

I am developing a macOS application and I am using sentry.io for crash reports. I triggered a crash in my app and I can see it logged in sentry. The problem is that when I see the crash report in Console.app, I see an "Application Specific Backtrace" which contains the name of the function that caused the crash, and I also see backtraces of many threads. On sentry I don't see the Application Specific Backtrace. What could be the reason for this? Note that I uploaded the relevant DSYM file.

Comment: How have you configured Sentry in your application? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020626/wait-until-sentry-sent-the-error-report-before-exiting-the-application) or [this tip from Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/apple/guides/macos/usage/#capturing-uncaught-exceptions-in-macos) may be relevant.